# MIT 6.0001 pset1 partC

Tags: python

[pset 1 partC](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf)

This is what I have now，but it keeps getting into infinite loops. Could someone please tell me what is wrong? Besides, I'm not sure how to deal with the case when it is not possible to save for the down payment in 36 months with a print statement.

```
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
r = 0.04
portion_down_payment = 0.25
total_cost = 1000000
epsilon = 100 
count = 0
low = 0
high = 10000
saving_rate_integer = (low + high) / 2

diff = 1000000

annual_salary = float(input("Please enter your annual salary: "))

monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
down_payment = portion_down_payment * total_cost
  
while abs(diff) >= 100:
    current_savings = 0
    num_month = 0
    while num_month <= 36:
        if num_month % 6 == 0 and num_month != 0:
            monthly_salary = monthly_salary * (1 + semi_annual_raise)
        monthly_interest = current_savings * r / 12
        current_savings = current_savings + monthly_interest + monthly_salary * (saving_rate_integer/ 10000)
        num_month += 1
        
    
    if current_savings < down_payment:
        low = saving_rate_integer
    else:
        high = saving_rate_integer
    saving_rate_integer = (low + high) / 2 
    
    count += 1
    diff = current_savings - down_payment
  
saving_rate_float = saving_rate_integer/ 10000
print("Saving rate: ", saving_rate_float)
print("Steps: ", count)
```

Comment: Couple of hints to help you solve the problem yourself. 1) I quote "Remember to reset the appropriate variable(s)"----> monthly_salary, 2) The case when it is not possible to save enough money is when you exhaust your search space. You might have to put a bit of thought on when this happens. Making these two changes got me the results with the `steps` in agreement

Answer (score 0):

If the starting salary is inadequate, the low rate will keep increasing until it nearly converges on the high rate (i.e. 10000; 100%; the entire salary).
The *if/else* statement for the savings rate gives a float. If you cast it to an integer (using *round*), you can force the loop to stop when the savings rate is equal to the upper limit.

```
while abs(current_savings - down_payment) > epsilon:
    step += 1
    current_savings = 0
    monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
    for month in range (0,35):        
            current_savings += current_savings*(r/12)
            current_savings += (monthly_salary*(savings_rate/10000))
            month += 1
            if month%6 == 0:
                monthly_salary *= (1+semi_annual_raise)
    if current_savings < down_payment:
        low_rate = savings_rate
    else:
        high_rate = savings_rate
    savings_rate = (round(low_rate + high_rate)/2)
    if savings_rate == 10000:
        break
```